# when subobject stops becoming one

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, lifetime, object-properties

Once an object is created which contains a few subobjects. Can those subobjects "stop" being subobjects at some point without the host object being completely re-used or destroyed?

For example:

```
struct A { int a; int b; };

A o;
new (&o.b) float{34.3}; // because **o** object storage is reused by a non-nesting object the lifetime of **o** shall end, is a still a subobject, or does it become a complete object?
```

On one hand, the standard says that the properties of an object determined at creation [http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#:~:text=The%20properties%20of%20an,%E2%80%94%C2%A0end%20note%5D](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#:%7E:text=The%20properties%20of%20an,%E2%80%94%C2%A0end%20note%5D)

But then that paragraph from the standard does list some properties. Does it mean that there are other properties that are just NOT listed?

On another hand, there is this paragraph in the standard that clearly says what a subobject is, and particularly it says that the host object must be within its lifetime...

[http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#:~:text=Objects%20can%20contain,cv%2Dqualification](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#:%7E:text=Objects%20can%20contain,cv%2Dqualification)).

Comment: There are open defects in relation to this topic. For example, when the lifetime of `o` ends the lifetime of `o.a` should also end, but nothing seems to specify this currently. Presumably a subobject shouldn't stop being a subobject, although I wouldn't be surprised if there are uses of "subobject" in the standard that should refer to _alive_ subobjects.

Comment: `new (o.b)` - shouldn't that be `new(&o.b)`?  Also, what is "it" that becomes a complete object in your comment?  Are you talking about `o.b`?  The objects named `o` nor `o.b` exist after the placement construction (and neither does `o.a`), as their lifetime has ended.  So ... what subobject are you talking about?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry typo, correct. I'm talking about *o.a* subject, as the lifetime of *o.b* ended explicitly and the lifetime of *o* ended just because its storage was re-used by a non-nesting subobject.  You say that a lifetime's ended as well? But the standard does not define it as been re-cursive though. I could not find anything that actually clearly says that *o.a* lifetime has ended.

Comment: You aren't allowed to reuse the storage of a subobject.  They can overlap.  Attempting to do so will end the lifetime of the full object.

Comment: More clear, of course, is `A o; auto p = &o.b; auto q = new (p) float{};`  It's the same pointer, and the placement new has the same effect (reusing the storage of `o` to create a complete `float` object).  But `o.b` is not a valid name for that new object.  Neither is `*p`.  Only `*q` is.

Comment: @BenVoigt using your example  say store a pointer to o.a before creating float? Could we still derefrence it after creating float? My  be point is that the fact that the lifetime of o ends , it is not clear from the standard that the lifetime of o.a would and it is clearly not potentially overlapping in this example

Comment: @minex: The standard has specific rules for that: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8 and in this situation it's not permitted.  [A subobject is never transparently replaceable by a complete object.](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#8.5)

Comment: @BenVoigt not sure how this relates to the pointer of *o.a* as it is not replaced in my example. Say,  *A o; auto& a = o.a; auto p = &o.b; auto q = new (p) float{}; a = 12// still good?*

Comment: No, it's a subobject of a complete object `o` whose lifetime has ended.

Comment: right correct, the lifetime of **o.b** has ended, and of **o** too. But my main question is whether the lifetime of **o.a** has ended too.

Comment: I don't know if there's a clause in the standard that says a subobject's lifetime is bounded by the lifetime of the complete object which contains it.  Such a thing ought to be part of the definition of "subobject".  Because the Standard doesn't define what happens to a subobject when a different part of the storage of its complete object is reused, it falls into "Undefined Behavior by omission".

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks! yeah, exactly that is what I was thinking as well. Surely there is a lot of code out in the wild that relies on **a.o** to be within a lifetime, so this shall probably be explicitly allowed

Comment: @BenVoigt why it is "undefined behavior by omission"? Could it not be the other way around - "if not forbidden then allowed"? As said if you say the object is in state A, once it is there, you should tell when it changes its state.

Comment: @minex: Because that's what "undefined" means.  The very definition of undefined behavior is "behavior for which this document [The C++ Standard] imposes no requirements".  The compiler can do anything it wants if you write code that uses a subobject after its parent's lifetime ends, because nothing it does would break any rule in the language spec.